# Haskell: Can you use the filter function to display a whole list by filtering nothing?

Tags: haskell

If I wanted to display the whole contents of a list, could you 'cheat' and use the filter function to filter nothing?

Comment: Then why are you filtering ?

Comment: Sure, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you're using GHCi, where (most) computations print their return value, and thus you're assuming that because running `filter` shows the resulting list that this is the "correct" way to show a list?

Comment: You want to print out every item in a list to the screen? `import Control.Monad; forM ["a", "b", "c"] putStrLn`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't display the list by filtering, because filtering doesn't display the list.

There is some serious conceptual confusion in your question.

Comment: Apparently so! I'm relatively new to Haskell and need to display a lists contents, so thought I'd ask just to check! I'll go back to my recursive function instead!

Comment: If you want to print a list, just use the `print` function.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just do

```
filter (const True) mylist
```

It would eat up extra processor time, and I don't know why you'd want to, but you can.

This operation is completely pointless though.  Through equational reasoning you can prove that `filter (const True) mylist === mylist`, so you gain nothing by "filtering" nothing from the list.

Comment: I asked the question under the (incorrect) assumption that filtering displayed the list, rather than just filtered it. Now that it's been pointed out it does seem rather pointless.

Comment: @Chillo Ah, I just assumed that you wanted to apply a no-op filter to a list before displaying it, or maybe you had a `displayFiltered :: Show a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> IO ()` function defined like `displayFiltered cond xs = print $ filter cond xs` and wanted to use it to display the whole list.

Comment: Thats... a little beyond me for now! :)